# Obj-C method naming: setup method

Tags: objective-c, methods, naming-conventions

Imagine an ordinary `UIViewController` subclass. We want to do "setup stuff" to be preformed before `-viewDidWhatever`, but the problem is that there are three methods that could possible be called, either `-initWithNibName`, `-initWithCoder` or simply `-init` depending on how it is created.

The solution would be to create `-setup` to be called from all these three, but I'm a bit unsure about the name. My question to you is: is there any standard naming of this method?

Comment: `setup` sounds fine, I'm not sure what you're expecting to get as a "right" answer here? And viewDidLoad is the traditional place for setup stuff in view controllers.

Comment: This is just personal preference so it will be closed. Personally I use a method called something like `- (void)commonInit;` purely so it still has the word init

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with setup being missed depending upon `init` or `initWithNibName:bundle:` being called, because they should both end up calling the designated initializer, whether that D.I. is one of them or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I have commonly named it `-setup` myself when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you could put it in `+ (void)initialize`, which is inherited from `NSObject` and will automatically be called before the class receives its first message.

Have a look here: [Apple Developer Library: NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize)

Comment: That method doesn't have access to any instance variables.